# How can I display an array in a tree view structure?

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, treeview

I want to build a tree view made of departments(parent) and sub-departments(child). In my database I think I have a good structure which is like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
 Dep_name         | dep_id | dep_parent_id    
--------------------------------------------
 Accounting       |    1   |        0
 Human-Resources  |    2   |        0
 IT               |    3   |        0
 Network          |    4   |        3
 Web Development  |    5   |        3
 Front-End        |    6   |        5
 Back-End         |    7   |        5
```

Departments which have the dep_parent_id 0 ---> they do not have a parent department. For example, Web Development and Network are children of IT department. Front End and Back End are children of Web Development.

I have found a recursive function which is appropriate to get all the data from this database table and put them on an array in te right structure. But the problem is that I dont know how to display this array like a tree view.
Like this for example

- Departments

  - Accounting
  - Human Resources
  - IT
  - Network
  - Web Development

    - Front End
    - Back End

..... and so on ....

In my database I think I have a good structure which is like this:

[image]

I have tried to print the array in a very simple way using

```
print_r($tree);
```

And it prints it like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [Dep_name] => Accounting and Finance
        [dep_id] => 1
        [dep_parent_id] => 0
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [Dep_name] => Human-Recources
        [dep_id] => 2
        [dep_parent_id] => 0
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [Dep_name] => IT
        [dep_id] => 3
        [dep_parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [Dep_name] => Network
                [dep_id] => 5
                [dep_parent_id] => 3
            )
            [1] => stdClass Object (
                [Dep_name] => Web Development
                [dep_id] => 6
                [dep_parent_id] => 3
                [children] => Array (
                    [0] => stdClass Object (
                        [Dep_name] => Front-End
                        [dep_id] => 7
                        [dep_parent_id] => 6
                    )
                    [1] => stdClass Object (
                        [Dep_name] => Back-End
                        [dep_id] => 8
                        [dep_parent_id] => 6
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [Dep_name] => Marketing
        [dep_id] => 4
        [dep_parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [Dep_name] => web-marketing
                [dep_id] => 9
                [dep_parent_id] => 4
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This is my function that gets data from database table from array $data and builds a tree array $branch.

```
function buildTree(array $data, $parentId = 0) 
{
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($data as $element) 
    {
        if ($element->dep_parent_id == $parentId) 
        {
            $children = buildTree($data, $element->dep_id);
            if ($children) 
            {
                $element->children = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }

    }

    return $branch;
}
```

And than I print it using :

```
print_r(buildTree($data));
```

I would be very grateful if you would help me to solve this and display a tree view structure in html from array $branch that I return from function `buildTree($data)`.

Comment: What's your question, exactly..? How to print it?

Comment: Yes I mean how can I print an array in a tree view structure using html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive function that checks if the `children` property of the object exists - and if it does, print out a new `<ul>` tag before looping those elements.

```php
function printTree($array) {
    $output = "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        $output .= "<li>".$a->Dep_name."</li>\n";

        if (isset($a->children)) {
            $output .= printTree($a->children);
        }
    }
    $output .= "</ul>\n";
    return $output;
}
```

This will return a single string that has the HTML in the hierarchy described. The output will be like this (well, not indented like this, but the HTML will print just the same)

```html
<ul>
    <li>Accounting and Finance</li>
    <li>Human-Recources</li>
    <li>IT</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Network</li>
        <li>Web Development</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Front-End</li>
                <li>Back-End</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>Marketing</li>
    <ul>
        <li>web-marketing</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/QUtVj

Answer (score 0):

```
function sort(array $array): array
{
    $sort = [];

    foreach($array as $item) {
        if ($item->dep_parent_id !== 0) {
            $sort[$item->dep_parent_id][$item->dep_id] = $item->Dep_name;
            continue;
        }

        $sort[$item->dep_id][0] = $item->Dep_name;
    }

    return $sort;
}

<ul>
    <?php foreach (sort($array) as $item): ?>
        <li><?= $item[0]?></li>
        <?php if (count($item) > 1): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php unset($item[0]); ?>
                <?php foreach($item as $value): ?>
                    <li><?= $value ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know how to build my array but I dont know how to display my array in form of a tree view using unordered lists in html for example. So I cannot use this as an answer for my question.